# Recursive Ng-include causing Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a recursive Ng-include which leads to Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

**In my ctrl:**

```
function getTemplate(elementType) {
        console.log(elementType + '_formElement.html');
        return elementType + '_formElement.html';
    };
```

**In my view:**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elementList track by $index" ng-init="templateID=vm.getTemplate(element.elementType)">
    <ng-include src="templateID"></ng-include>
</div>
```

**Result:** 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function
>   (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return
>   b(f,c,e)}","newVal":3},{"msg":"fn: function (a){return
>   d(a)}","newVal":""},{"msg":"templateID","newVal":"ROW_formElement.html"}],[{"msg":"fn:
>   function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return
>   b(f,c,e)}","newVal":3},{"msg":"fn: function (a){return
>   d(a)}","newVal":""},{"msg":"templateID","newVal":"ROW_formElement.html"}],[{"msg":"fn:
>   function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return
>   b(f,c,e)}","newVal":3},{"msg":"fn: function (a){return
>   d(a)}","newVal":""},{"msg":"templateID","newVal":"ROW_formElement.html"}],[{"msg":"fn:
>   function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return
>   b(f,c,e)}","newVal":3},{"msg":"fn: function (a){return
>   d(a)}","newVal":""},{"msg":"templateID","newVal":"FIELD_formElement.html"}],[{"msg":"templateID","newVal":"TEXT_field.html"},{"msg":"fn:
>   function (a){return d(a)}","newVal":""}]]

**Console.log:**

```
  ROW_formElement.html
7 ROW_formElement.html
  FIELD_formElement.html
```

I know I can increase TTL like following, **but is there any other solution?**

`angular.module('myApp',[])
.config(function($rootScopeProvider) {
    $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(number); //some number bigger then 10
})`

Comment: Can you provide a working code sample somehow? The digest cycle seems to re-re-re-re-run by continious value changes.

Comment: What does the `getTemplate()` function do?

Comment: It's the function I have posted, sorry i changed its name. I will try to create a plnkr when I have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, I think there is no error in my code.

As answered [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705) and shown in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eswdk9FW8E4Q3v426Oq4?p=preview) this is just how angular works. 
There seems to be no other solution other than setting a higher digest TTL number than 10.

`angular.module('myApp',[])
.config(function($rootScopeProvider) {
    $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(number); //some number bigger then 10
})`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I followed the advice on this link and it worked!:

[Building Nested Recursive Directives in Angular](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/)